# PhoneGap Doesn't Run in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I have a PhoneGap application that launches the app in my Android phone with **phonegap run android** but, does not do the same with iOS. My iPhone has been registered with the Apple Developer Program and I am able to run my app once I open it with Xcode and build into my device.

Here is my Terminal snapshot:

```
MacBook-Pro:my-app nagarjun$ sudo phonegap run --device ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
[phonegap] successfully compiled iOS app
[phonegap] installing app onto device
```

While it compiles and tells me that it is installing the app on the device, it really doesn't.

Comment: did you face any error

Comment: Nope, no error whatsoever. It simply stops at installing app into device and lets me enter Terminal commands. I then have to go to Xcode and clean the product. Then launch it from there. It does work that way.

Comment: reset your simulator and then try it

Comment: What is the simulator? Did you mean emulator? If so, I am not using the emulator. I want it to run on my device.

Comment: If you have already compiled the app on to the phone, then the reason it's not showing up is because you have the app already on the phone. So double check to see if the app is already there, because in that case cordova is simply replacing it.

Comment: @Timothy_Bone I do already have the app on the phone but, it doesn't seem to replace it because once I launch the app after running the command, my new changes don't appear on it.

Comment: Try running: cordova run ios -d 
hopefully that will give more useful information to dig into

also just for kicks, try deleting the app so it can reinstall afresh